# Firebase range query startAt and endAt on a combined field not giving expected results

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am using firebase in my project where I am implementing filters on the backend.I have a list of articles which has the following structure

```
{
   -KjhqsRdqbt1YqmJK01R:{
    ...related_fields,
    identifiers:{
        "CUS-CAT":"enzen-CAT-10-15-05"
    },
   -another_id:{
     ...related_fields,
    identifiers:{
        "CUS-CAT":"trimble-CAT-30-05-05"
    },
   }
}
```

I try to run a query 
`ref.orderByChild("identifiers/CUS-CAT").startAt("enzen-CAT-10-00-00").endAt("enzen-CAT-10-99-99")`

I expect atleast one result '-KjhqsRdqbt1YqmJK01R' running the above query but I get zero results. In fact running a query with startAt("enzen-CAT-10-15-05").endAt("enzen-CAT-10-99-99") does'nt work.

I could not figure out where I am making a mistake`(while querying or while storing the combination)`.I ve been dealing with this for days, trying all the possible combinations but no luck still.Any help would be helpful.Thanks

Comment: We need to be able to see more of your code. Like how is your 'ref' defined and how do you deal with the DataSnapshot you receive

Comment: You should first make sure that you receiving some data without the `startAt` and `endAt` to pinpoint the problem to querying.